# How to link to amazon web store from browser in a kindle?

Tags: android, url, app-store, kindle, amazon-appstore

I want to redirect the user to kindle web store directly from my website. Is there a way to do it? I already tried using "amzn://apps/android?asin=B004FRX0MY" but I guess this works only to redirect user to another app when he is already inside web store.

PS: the whole scenario exist when user is using browser in kindle